# Extracting Cities from Text File

Tags: shell, command-line, command

I have a huge list of cities in a text file but need to extract just the cities.

Here's the format:

```
Country,City,AccentCity,Region,Population,Latitude,Longitude
ad,aixas,Aixàs,06,,42.4833333,1.4666667
ad,aixirivali,Aixirivali,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirivall,Aixirivall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirvall,Aixirvall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
```

Would it be possible to extract just the cities and output them to another file via command line?

Thanks!

Comment: Learn to use `awk` or `sed` or `cut`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{FS=","; print $2}' < file
```